# How to downgrade jquery version in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm facing some bootstrap problem with jquery 3.5.0 in Laravel. I'm trying to downgrade my jquery to 3.4.1 version but then when I edit the package.json and run composer update my jquery version doesn't change. Can anyone solve my problem?
Below is my package.json file.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan refer to this link https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30553?fbclid=IwAR1WzDFxVQlBgA9Kidn6AIGli9rhiw64-JnUL3Eg2LPaXWpMDlmBiArZ9Yo

Comment: You're right, I forgot 4.4.2 isn't publicly available yet

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to downgrade jquery version (or any other npm package) in any project including Laravel is this:

1. Inside `package.json` you set which version you want, for example:

   ```
   "jquery": "3.4.1",
   ```
2. delete node_modules folder (if already created)
3. delete package-lock.json file (if already there)
4. run `npm install` - this will install the wanted versions of packages inside package.json
5. (only for Laravel) run `npm run dev` - to recompile everything again (with changed version/s of packages)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but for those who just searching around and needs a quick answer for like me, here we goes.

Do the same changes like OP, on `package.json` (to change the jQuery version).

Then, on CLI, run this command

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

I'm not the NPM guy / an expert guy (neither Laravel expert).
But, here the explanation,

> Seems we need to run `npm install`, to get the related package and copy it into our node_modules folder.
>
> Then, for `npm run dev`, it's for compiling our assets (Assuming you're using Laravel default scaffolding)

That's it. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it old-school style. Hardcode it in your html template:

1.Insert

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

2.In **resources/js/app.js** file, delete **require('./bootstrap')**

3.Don't import bootstrap in your **app.scss** file.

You can still compile anything required inside your **app.js** and **app.scss**