# Can't downgrade jquery version in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to downgrade jquery version from 3.5.0 to 3.4.1, I have tried to change it in package.json file but it shows the same 3.5.0 version. My bootstrap responsive navbar is not working with this version

After running npm install command it goes to 3.5.1 and in webpage console it is showing 3.5.0

```
"dependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^3.0.5",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1"
    }
```

Tried this solution but didn't work
[How to downgrade jquery version in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427089/how-to-downgrade-jquery-version-in-laravel)

npm install error

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...uy5sAF7TiUYHSa25iamul'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your

- node_modules folder
- package-lock.json file

in laravel app, set the jquery to `"jquery": "3.4.1"` and run `npm install && npm run dev`

Comment: again in package.json it changed to 3.5.1

Comment: did you remove package-lock.json

Comment: "jquery": "3.4.1" this line will be in "devDependencies": { } or "Dependencies": { } ?

Comment: devDependencies

Comment: by deleting package-lock.json file didn't complete npm install normally

Comment: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
got this at the end of npm install command

Comment: In package.json it show 3.4.1 but on webpage console it is 3.5.0

Comment: That 3.5.0 version in console is because that is THE LAST successfully compiled version... you need to fix your dependencies and take care of that npm ERR and make it compile without errors and then you will have jquery version 3.4.1

Comment: Update your question with that error you get when you try to `npm install` but first delete node_modules and package-lock.json again and then run npm-install

Comment: I have updated the question with the error I'm getting

Comment: OK, so I think you have updated the node version OR you have moved your code where some newer node js version is installed and that's why you are having problems! The only solution here is to update everything what is needed in that error... or downgrade the node js.... You can't have all.... you will need to decide what to do!

Comment: So, How can I update these thing which I am getting errors? And how the node js be downgraded

Comment: Create a new question on SO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823900/how-to-update-errors-i-am-getting-when-running-npm-install-in-laravel